# auto-align forms when they are shown

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have 4 fourms, and when form1 shows(), it calls to show the other 3.  How can I make it so when it shows the other forms it will auto align it with the first one?

```
-Form 1 shows
-Need form2 to attach it to the left of form 1
-Need form3 to attach it to the bottom of form 1
-Need form4 to attach it to the right of form 1
```

So it looks like one form with 4 different sections.  The reason is i would like the center form (form 1 ) to run openGL and the other 3 forms for controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need such a function then I would suggest using the[`TJvFormMagnet`](http://jvcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jvcl/trunk/jvcl/run/JvFormMagnet.pas?revision=13167&view=markup) component of the [JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/) (JEDI Visual Component Library).

Otherwise you could simply calculate the ClientRect & position of the side forms whenever the MainForm moves or resizes by catching the appropriate messages via WndProc method.